# Add javascript function to wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a page that locates a link inside it and when that link is clicked it should save some data in database.

Besides, I have a file named "add.php" that communicates with the DB and operates well.

In my wordpress page I have added below codes for accessing the add.php file and send some parameters to it.

```
<a href="javascript:add(true);" >Click Me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(b){
$(document).ready(function(){
        var result = $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "add.php",
              data: { add: b }

            });

            result.done(function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
            });

            result.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "No such data exists: " + textStatus );
            });
    });
}
</script>
```

I had this exact code in an html file and it worked smoothly. but it doesn't work on wordpress page like that.
Plus, the problem is that when I click the link -Click Me- it doesn't do anything.

please tell me where the problem is and how to solve it ?

Comment: why doc ready to be wrapped in a function like that? and you should use `jQuery` instead of `$` or change to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: @Jai thanks for reply. I am new in this stuff and this is a code my friend gave me and it works fine in an html file but not in wordpress page. You think the problem is that ?

Comment: yes there could be several issues like, `doc ready` applied in a function, `$` is used while `jQuery` is used by wp and instead of calling that function in the href you can bind a click event by applying a class name to the anchor and pass the required data via `data-*` attribute and you can use that function as a callback directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use this:

```
<a href="#" data-add="true" class='hitClick'>Click Me</a>
<!--use data* attributes to pass specific data -->
```

now in your function:

```js
function add() {
  event.preventDefault(); //<------make sure to add it.
  var result = jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add.php",
    data: {
      add: jQuery(this).data('add')
    }

  });

  result.done(function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  });

  result.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("No such data exists: " + textStatus);
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hitClick').on('click', add); // bind the click and use as callback
});
```

Comment: Where are you putting this code in the page or external js file?

Comment: in the page that I created in wordpress. in text style if it

Comment: check console for error? or try wrapping click event in doc ready block.

Comment: I don't know where it is. how to check it ?

Comment: Now I checked on the console error and the error is that add is not defined. how is it possible ?